# lua script to femm42: can't seem to find where that bug is

Tags: lua, simulation, physics

I'm new to Lua, and I need to use it in femm42. I wrote this script which is supposed to read every line of a simulation .res file, but it tells me there's supposed to be a = in line 9.

```
showconsole()

mydir = "./"
resfile = "embpIV.res"
open(mydir .. "EMBPMkIV.fem")
mi_saveas(mydir .. "temp.fem")
io.input(resfile)

for line in io.lines(resfile) do

    local t, i = io.read("*number", "*number")

    mi_modifycircprop("Coil", 1, i)
    mi_analyse()
    mi_loadsolution()
    mo_addcontour(0, 7)
    mo_addcontour(0, 2.5)
    mo_addcontour(0, -2)
    mo_makeplot(1, 500, mydir .. "fem res/" .. t .. ".res", 0)

end

mo_close()
mi_close()
```

Can you guys help me out?

Comment: Your script is syntactically correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *guess* it's a problem with spaces, so try to edit your code line by line. For example, copy all lines before 9th line and check and then add line by line and check.

Also, a full error message is needed in order to help you.